# How to stop a setInterval function using an onPress trigger in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have this function which calls another function every second using setInterval:

```
  startCameraMode = () => {
    setInterval(() => this.takePicture(), 1000)
  }
```

I am tring to stop it using this expression using clearInterval:

```
clearInterval(this.startCameraMode)
```

Here:

```
<ActionButton.Item useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="Stop" onPress={clearInterval(this.startCameraMode)}>
<Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
</ActionButton.Item>
```

However, I get this error:

```
ActionButton.props.onPress is not a function
```

How can I stop this setInterval from functioning using the onPress prop? If this is not possible I would like to know other ways to accomplish that.

The whole code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native'
import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera'
import { CameraRoll } from 'react-native'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'
import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions'
import ActionButton from 'react-native-action-button'
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons'


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  button: {
    height: 200,

    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

  actionButtonIcon: {
    fontSize: 20,
    height: 22,
    color: 'white',
  },

  buttonLeft: {
    marginRight: 100,
    height: 200,
    justifyContent: 'flex-end',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },

});


export default class Cam extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.takePicture = this.takePicture.bind(this)
    this.state = {
      interval: 0,
      unit: 'second(s)',
      cameraModeOn: false
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.requestStorage()

    getIntervalData = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('interval')
        if(value !== null) {
          let numberDecimalValue = parseFloat(value)
          this.setState({interval: numberDecimalValue})
        }
      } catch(error) {
        alert(error)
      }
    }
    getIntervalData()

    getUnitData = async () => {
      try {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('unit')
        if(value !== null) {
          this.setState({unit: value})
        }
      } catch(error) {
        alert(error)
      }
    }
    getUnitData()

  }

  requestStorage = async function() {
    Permissions.check('storage').then(response => {
      if (response != 'authorized') {
        Permissions.request('storage')
      }
    })
  }

  takePicture = async function() {
    if (this.camera) {
      const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true }
      const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
      CameraRoll.saveToCameraRoll(data.uri)
    }
  }

  startCameraMode = () => {
    setInterval(() => this.takePicture(), 1000)
  }

  stop

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>

        <RNCamera
          ref={ref => {this.camera = ref}}
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: '100%',
            position: 'relative'
          }}
          type={RNCamera.Constants.Type.back}
          androidCameraPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use camera',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your camera',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
          androidRecordAudioPermissionOptions={{
            title: 'Permission to use audio recording',
            message: 'We need your permission to use your audio',
            buttonPositive: 'Ok',
            buttonNegative: 'Cancel',
          }}
        >
        </RNCamera>

        <ActionButton size={80} useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)">
          <ActionButton.Item useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor='#9b59b6' title="Settings" onPress={this.props.switchScreen}>
            <Icon name="md-create" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>

          <ActionButton.Item useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="Stop" onPress={clearInterval(this.startCameraMode)}>
            <Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>

          <ActionButton.Item useNativeFeedback={false} buttonColor='#1abc9c' title="Start" onPress={this.startCameraMode}>
            <Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
          </ActionButton.Item>

        </ActionButton>

      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to call clearInterval with the returned value from setInterval.

Edit startCameraMode to:

```
startCameraMode = () => {
  this.isTakingPictures = setInterval(() => this.takePicture(), 1000)
}
```

And the button to:

```
<ActionButton.Item 
  useNativeFeedback={false} 
  buttonColor='#1abc9c' 
  title="Stop" 
  onPress={
   if(this.isTakingPictures != undefined) { 
     clearInterval(this.isTakingPictures);
     this.isTakingPictures = undefined;
   }
  }>
  <Icon name="md-done-all" style={styles.actionButtonIcon} />
</ActionButton.Item>
```

It seems to me you also need to take care of firing multiple startCameraMode, as pressing the button multiple times would lead to mulitple scheduling with setInterval, and clear interval, as written here, would only clear the last one.

Answer (score 1):

The setInterval function returns a pointer.

So do something like this:

```
startCameraMode = () => {
   this.intervalPointer = setInterval(() => this.takePicture(), 1000)
}
...
onPress={clearInterval(this.intervalPointer)}
```